# Tomcat JNDI Resouce Not Accessible

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jndi

I have gone through all the posts on the above subject but have not been able to resolve this. The situation is like this:

1) I have defined a set of resources in conf/server.xml (GlobalNamingResources) of Tomcat 8.0.20
2) I have declared ResourceLink in tomcat conf/context.xml
3) From the web application I am getting name not bound exception.

As per my understanding, the resources declared in server.xml will be accessible from a context if it is mapped in the ResourceLink, now the conf/context.xml is loaded for all the web applications and the resources should be available but they are not. Am I missing something.

Below are the files:

The Exception

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this   Context
. Unable to find [comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.hm.vigil.platform.db.DatabaseConnectionManager.<init>(DatabaseConnectionManager.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

The server.xml

```
    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
    <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
    -->
    <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"   SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
        <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

        <Resource name="pool/LDAP"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="com.hm.vigil.platform.ldap.LDAPConnectionManager"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.ldap.LDAPConnectionManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeLDAPConnectionManager"/>

        <Resource name="platform/ZOOKEEPER"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.PlatformConfigManager"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.PlatformConfigManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeZookeeperConfigRetriever"/>

        <Resource name="pool/DB_CLIENT"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.Datasource"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.db.DatabaseConnectionManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeDatabaseConnectionManager"/>

        <Resource name="platform/client/CONFIG_MANAGER"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.ClientConfigManager"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.ClientConfigManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeClientConfigManager"/>

        <Environment name="zooKeeperHost" 
                     type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="localhost" 
                     override="false"/>   

        <Environment name="zookeeperPort" 
                     type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="2181" 
                     override="false"/>                                                       

  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->

      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>


      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <!-- <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/> -->

         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
                connectionURL="ldap://localhost:10389"
                connectionName="uid=admin,ou=system"
                connectionPassword="secret"
                userBase="cn=PLATFORM_CLIENTS,cn=PLATFORM_CONFIG,dc=example,dc=com"
                userSubtree="true"
                userSearch="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(email={0})(userClass=ACTIVE))"
                userRoleName="userRole"/>

      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->

        <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" /> -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.authenticator.ClusterSingleSignOn" />
        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

<!--          <Context>
            <Environment name="zooKeeperHost" 
                     type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="localhost" 
                     override="false"/>

            <Environment name="zookeeperPort" 
                     type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="2181" 
                     override="false"/>
         </Context> -->

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

The context.xml

```
    <Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!--        <Environment name="zooKeeperHost" 
                     type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="localhost" 
                     override="false"/> -->

        <ResourceLink name="zooKeeperHost"
                      global="zooKeeperHost"
                      type="java.lang.String"/>                  

<!--        <Environment name="zookeeperPort" 
                     type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="2181" 
                     override="false"/> -->

        <ResourceLink name="zookeeperPort"
                      global="zookeeperPort"
                      type="java.lang.String"/>

<!--         <Resource name="pool/LDAP"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="com.hm.vigil.platform.ldap.LDAPConnectionManager"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.ldap.LDAPConnectionManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeLDAPConnectionManager"/> -->

        <ResourceLink name="pool/LDAP"
                      global="pool/LDAP"
                      type="com.hm.vigil.platform.ldap.LDAPConnectionManager"/>

<!--          <Resource name="platform/ZOOKEEPER"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.PlatformConfigManager"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.PlatformConfigManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeZookeeperConfigRetriever"/> -->

        <ResourceLink name="platform/ZOOKEEPER"
                      global="platform/ZOOKEEPER"
                      type="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.ZookeeperConfigRetriever"/>

<!--         <Resource name="pool/DB_CLIENT"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.Datasource"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.db.DatabaseConnectionManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeDatabaseConnectionManager"/> -->

        <ResourceLink name="pool/DB_CLIENT"
                      global="pool/DB_CLIENT"
                      type="javax.sql.Datasource"/>

<!--         <Resource name="platform/client/CONFIG_MANAGER"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.ClientConfigManager"
                  factory="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.ClientConfigManager"
                  singleton="true"
                  closeMethod="closeClientConfigManager"/> -->

        <ResourceLink name="platform/client/CONFIG_MANAGER"
                      global="platform/client/CONFIG_MANAGER"
                      type="com.hm.vigil.platform.config.ClientConfigManager"/>                                                           

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->

    <Manager pathname="" />

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

Thanks

Comment: The name of any resource in Tomcat starts with `java:comp`.

Comment: Yes, the JNDI resolution is initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env"), then context.lookup("zookeeperHost")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall post my findings as to the above problems.

The problem is that one/more of the resources have internal reference to another resource that is bound to the JNDI tree. So during creation of the resources attempt is made by the other resources to resolve the JNDI tree for the common resource. Now, at the tis time of context loading the JNDI tree for that context actually does not exist, so the above error.

The way round was to declare a factory method on the common resource and from the other resources get the reference to the common resource through the factory method.

So, as a general principal, I feel, resources must not resolve other resources from JNDI.